# component is being flagged by CheckMarx as vulnerable with is error

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, sanitization

checkmarx error  in Angular  - S and details, untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

we have the below code in Angular

1)In component variable 'S' is assigned with plain string and S variable is binded in html ,  CheckMarx reporting s as vulnerable

public S = "loading";

In HTML

<p> {{ S}} </p>

{{ S }}

Q: How to sanitize the variable S which is having plain text in angular?

2)Q: how to sanitize the below obejct( this.details- whih is having the json data) in Angular

```
function() {

     this.abcService.getDetails(this.queryParams.requestId).subscribe(
       data => { this.details =   data; }   
  },
```

As per my analysis I can c the functions to sanitize the URL, HTML , SCRIPT only , Please help how to sanitize the plain text  and object in angular Thanks.

I have tried with below approach, but checkmark still marking it as a vulnerable

```
 this.details = (decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(data)));
```

Comment: you can start googling with this keyword "Dom sanitize angular", https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Dom context we can apply only for HTML, script,url It seems. dont find the method to sanitize a variable which is having the plain text or an object ..... mark a value as trusted, inject DomSanitizer and call one of the following methods:

1)bypassSecurityTrustHtml
2)bypassSecurityTrustScript
3)bypassSecurityTrustStyle
4)bypassSecurityTrustUrl
5)bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Comment: nah, variable is just, well, a variable, it doesn't have any function until you use it. So the var is used in html, then use the trusthtml, if it's used in script, use trustscript